# Is there a way to create an Eclipse project excluding the project name in the path?

Tags: php, eclipse, web

Not sure how I can explain this better as I am a beginner to Eclipse application.

I have my web directory set up for php pages. For example, /home/www/phpsite. All the source files exist here.

However, whenever I create a project (say 'myProject') and test any files from the existing path, it includes the project folder in the path name:
/home/www/phpsite/myProject/index.php 
and this results 'Not Found' error.

How can I run my php pages in /home/www/phpsite/index.php? The project folder name is always included in testing web pages.

I am not trying to use the workspace directory created by Eclipse. I'd like to code and modify pages directly from Eclipse to my web directory.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have your site on a local webserver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Follow these steps:**

- Setup **www** as your workspace
- From the menu: **File -> Import -> General -> Existing Folder**.....

**Promote to project:**

- Choose project type: PHP
- Browse for "**phpsite**" and finish.

Comment: It was a guess ..  ;-) .. glad it helped. You can accept the answer. it will close this question. Happy coding! And welcome to SO.

Comment: wow, that's amazing to give answer by a guess and I hope I can do the same thing in the future, thanks for your warm wish :)